# Replace hardcoded link with an image

Tags: css

I want to replace an a tag link for an image.

My link looks like the following:

```
<li id="backto-page"><a href="portfolio.html">&larr; Back to the Porfolio</a></li>
```

Now I have simply use the following css, but now the link doesn't work.. Only the text inside de id backto-page a tag will invisible and the background image will show up.. When you hover over the link also there will be no pointer be visible...

```
li#backto-page {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: #000 url(../images/list-icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to the `li#backto-page a` in your CSS.

```
li#backto-page a {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5KNAt/

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I searching for!

Comment: Must wait some seconds for accept your answer! ;) One question I came up now, is it also possible to replace text for another text with css or is this for javascript?

Comment: That's a job for Javascript (you can use CSS pseudo-selectors - `:before` and `:after` to an extent, but it's not entirely cross browser); look at Neo's answer below and change the `<img src="` etc. to the text of your choice...

Answer (score 0):

Try it with jquery

```
   $(function(){
        $("#backto-page").html('<img src="../images/list-icon.png"/>');

    })
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but jQuery really isn't needed for this as it can be solved using CSS.